# How can I get the value of a widget the exact moment a button is clicked FLTK

Tags: c++, clr, fltk

The goal is to be able to get the value of a widget such as FL_Input when I click my button.

One way I could do this is by using events and classes. Such as

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyButton : public Fl_Button
{
    static int count;
public:
    MyButton(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char*l = 0)
        :Fl_Button(x, y, w, h, l) {}

    int handle(int e)
    {
        int ret = Fl_Button::handle(e);
        //test - - - cout << endl << count++ << " ******** button " << label() << " receives ";


        switch (e)
        {
        case FL_PUSH:
            trigger..
            break;


        }
        return(ret);
    }

};

int MyButton::count = 0;

void but_a_cb(Fl_Widget* w, void* v) {
    cout << endl << "Button A callback!" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    Fl_Window win(120, 150);
    win.begin();

    MyButton but_a(10, 10, 100, 25, "A");
    but_a.shortcut('a');
    but_a.callback(but_a_cb);


    win.end();
    win.show();
    return(Fl::run());
}
```

However, this is not an optimal way of doing this for me because I want to take multiple inputs and put them in a vector and use them in this. To do this i am thinking of an input callback that will return the input value and I would use a "Fl_Input->when(FL_CHANGED)"

Preferably I would be able to get the values and put them into a vector on button click by using code in the main function and not the button because this would require me to rework my program to implement this.

Just declaring the vector in the main doesn't work due to it taking the value on form load.

Summarising, I want to know how I can create something like an if statement that is triggered when a button is clicked to get values of fl_inputs at the moment when the button is clicked. T

*Note I am going to implement this with a database so that I will need it to work with CLR*

Extra code I have came up with

```
void done_cb(Fl_Widget* w, void* param)
{
    Fl_Input* i = (Fl_Input*)param;
    string inputstring = i->value();
    cout << inputstring;

    // What i tried for the vectors
    //vector<Fl_Input*> v = *reinterpret_cast<vector<Fl_Input*> *>(param);
    //string inputstring = v[0]->value();
    //cout << inputstring;
    
}
void signupScreen (void) {

    Fl::event_dispatch(myHandler);
    

    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(200, 150);
    window->begin();
    int x = 50, y = 10, w = 100, h = 30;

    y += 35;
    

    y += 35;
    Fl_Input *input2 = new Fl_Input(x, 10, w, h, "str");
    
    Fl_Button* done = new Fl_Button(x, y, 100, h, "Done");
    done->when(FL_WHEN_CHANGED);
    
    string strinput;

    //strinput = input2->value();
    
    //input2->when(FL_WHEN_CHANGED);

        
    //std::vector<Fl_Input*> v = { input2 };
    done->callback(done_cb, input2);

    

    cout << strinput;
    
    window->end();
    

    window->show();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define a new class derivated from `Fl_Input` which has a member of type `std::vector<std::string>` where you store the text written in your input field.

```
#ifndef __MYINPUT_H
#define __MYINPUT_H
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Input.H>
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>


class myinput: public Fl_Input
{    
    public:
        /* 
        Instead of setting it public, you may create get and set methods.
        */
        std::vector<std::string> _storing;
        // Constructor 
        myinput(int x, int y, int h, int l, std::vector<std::string> S, const char* ll = 0);
        ~myinput(){};
        
};

#endif
```

The `.ccp` file:

```
#include <myinput.hpp>

myinput::myinput(int x, int y, int h, int l,std::vector<std::string> S,const char* ll):Fl_Input(x, y, h,l,ll)
{
    _storing = S;
}
```

Then, you may use it as shown below:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <myinput.hpp>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>

void add_cb(Fl_Widget* w, void* p){
    myinput* i = (myinput*)p;
    std::string inputstring = i->value();
    i->_storing.push_back(inputstring);

    // Just to show that it is working
    std::cout<< "Updated string:" << std::endl;
    for (int j=0; j<i->_storing.size(); j++ )
        std::cout << i->_storing[j] << std::endl;
}
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Fl_Window *G_win = 0;
    G_win = new Fl_Window(300,300,"Test");

    myinput* A;
    // Where you may store the strings
    std::vector<std::string> mytext;

    A = new myinput(100,50,100,20, mytext,"Insert text");

    Fl_Button* add;

    add = new Fl_Button(250,50,25,25,"+");
    add->callback(add_cb,A);


    G_win->end();
    G_win->show(argc, argv);
    
    return Fl::run();
}
```

If you want to store the strings coming from several input fields, you may collect the `Fl_input` inside a `Fl_Group` and pass the latter to the button's callback.

Please note that the code that I wrote is not very elegant nor it is the most efficient: it was just to show you my idea to solve your problem (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. However this does give me some errors in which I do not know how to solve

These errors are

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0349 no operator "<<" matches these operands FLTK tests D:\Visual Studio Projects\FLTK tests transferring\FLTK tests\FLTK tests\FLTK tests.cpp 14 
Warning C4018 '<': signed/unsigned mismatch FLTK tests d:\visual studio projects\fltk tests transferring\fltk tests\fltk tests\fltk tests.cpp 13 
Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

@Eddymage
+Eddymage

Comment: The only remaining errors are 

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion) FLTK tests d:\visual studio projects\fltk tests transferring\fltk tests\fltk tests\fltk tests.cpp 14 

//NEW LINE ***********
Error (active) E0349 no operator "<<" matches these operands FLTK tests D:\Visual Studio Projects\FLTK tests transferring\FLTK tests\FLTK tests\FLTK tests.cpp 15

Comment: Errors solved now new error:://
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall myinput::myinput(int,int,int,int,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > >,char const *)" (??0myinput@@QAE@HHHHV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main FLTK tests

Comment: @NewProgrammer00 I added the cpp source for the new class: I forgot it in the 1st version of the answer.